# Crystal Report, fitting a data from Database Horizontally

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I just want to ask if anyone here knows a work around for this.
So I've been trying to fix this for days.

I have a data from my database that looks like this:

```
******************************************
11/3/2021 8:46 AM

*Receipt Title
*Company
*Address Line
*City
*Building
*Contact #

Station                                POS
Cashier                LastName, FirstName
Receipt ID                         ASD1001
Session                   3735318968998975

1  Coca-cola                         $2.00


Total           $2.00
VAT@10% @ 10.00%:                    $0.18

Payment

Cash                                 $2.00

Total Payments                       $2.00
Change                               $0.00

_________________________________________
Tax ID240F
_________________________________________


Thank You
and
see you
soon

******************************************
```

Note that this data is stored in a single field/column, meaning you can't break them apart unless you concatenate it which will be very hard since that's a lot of characters and it changes depending on the purchased items of course.

Now when I connected this to my Crystal Report, it will look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzOOD.png

and it's frustrating how this should really be a simple problem but nothing that I tried worked.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Justified the formula field
2. Switched text formatting to HTML and used "pre" tag (it justified but all the break lines are gone, also I don't think it's ideal since it's a desktop application)
3. Tight Horizontal/ly
4. Changing margin size
5. Changing character spacing (makes the texts unreadable)

Hope someone can help.

Comment: What about using a monospaced font?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to update this, I've already fixed this by using a monospace font. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a monospace font did the trick. Works well with changing the character spacing.